# Gulp require(Path) is Different to fs.existsSync(Path)

Tags: node.js, gulp

I would like to override default variables with developer specific variables if a developer specific file exists.

the paths to various files are as follows:

```
// Gulp File
appPath\gulpfile.js

// Gulp Tasks
appPath\gulp\* 

// Gulp Developer Settings
appPath\gulp-config\*
```

I'm using `fs.existsSync(path)` to test if a developer settings file exists and if it does I use `require(path)` to include that file.

The problem I have is that the relative path for `fs.existsSync(path)` is different to the relative path for `require(path)`.

```
// I don't understand why the check for file and the require of that file, need slightly different paths
var developerConfigFile = './gulp-config/' + process.env.NODE_DEV + '.js';
var developerConfigFileForRequire = '../gulp-config/' + process.env.NODE_DEV + '.js';


if (fs.existsSync(developerConfigFile)) {
  console.log('Found: ' + developerConfigFile);
  require(developerConfigFileForRequire);
} else {
  console.log('NOT Found: ' + developerConfigFile);
}
```

[image: Gulp require(Path) is Different to fs.existsSync(Path)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's because relative paths that you give to `fs` functions (and anything that just uses filesystem paths) will be interpreted *relative to the current working directory*. Whereas a relative path passed to `require` is in interpreted *relative to the directory in which the module that is executing the `require` is located*. The two will be equal only in a limited number of cases. In your case, your current working directory is the top of your project tree, whereas when `gulp/conf.js` loads a module with a relative path, the starting directory is `gulp`, which is why you have to start your path with `..`.

Note that the optional loading could be simplified to something like this:

```
try {
    require(path_to_module);
}
catch (e) {
    if (e.code !== "MODULE_NOT_FOUND")
        throw e;
}
```

The `if` in the `catch` is so that `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` is ignored but other exceptions are rethrown.